# Add some text next to an element on a wordpress page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[Image to show postion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9oiY.png)

Hello there,

I would like to add a label to the box below (where it says 209) in the same style and aligned to the text above. These boxes are generated trough plugins. I have css styled them a bit, but I am unsure how to add text. Any help would be apreciated, since I am but only a humble noob.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a code writing service, you are expected to at least try yourself then come back with specific questions and show us what you've tried if you run into issues

Comment: my first question would be if you have access to the template to change the markup? Otherwise you would have to add the text via Javascript.

Comment: If you want us to have a look at the coding and how to manipulate that, we need to see what the code is. So a picture is not enough, share your page and we can help more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with jQuery:

```
jQuery('.classNameHere').text('text to be inserted');
```